# Extracting A Single Solution From Sage

Tags: python, sage

I'm working on a project in Sage that requires Sage to solve an underdetermined system.  I understand that the variables such as 'r956' are free variables once I run the solve command.  I have given Sage some assumptions on my symbolic variables and wish to know if there's a way to ask Sage to generate a single solution in which the free variables are assigned some arbitrary values which are consistent with the system of equations along with the given assumptions.  I feel like Sage should have some capability to do this but I cannot find an example.

Comment: Please provide Sage input and output for such a system, and an imaginary input together with the desired output.